# Can I use style binding with arrow function in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to bind styles with arrow functions in Vue JS HTML templates. My intention is to show/hide a div coming from the `vuex` store.

Here is my attempt to do it. `main_activity_opened` is already called to component via `mapState`.

```
<div 
   class="main-panel"
   :style="{ display: () => main_activity_opened ? 'block' : 'none' }">
```

It doesn't work. I want to know if this approach is a good idea, and if it's possible to do, suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the style of an element using the object notation, as in your example.

However, you cannot provide a function as a property value and expect the returned value of the function to be used in the element's inline style.

Simply set the value directly:

```
:style="{ display: main_activity_opened ? 'block' : 'none' }">
```